# I had a kind of feeling this might happen. (what is object?)

Tags: nouns, prepositional-phrases, direct-objects

I had a kind of feeling this might happen.

1. a kind
2. feeling

[a kind]*noun* **of** [feeling this might happen]noun phrase

I wonder which object is correct.

Comment: I'd say ***kind of / kinda*** in such contexts is simply an (entirely optional) ***adjectival/adverbial*** element, as in *It's **kind of** pointless, he **kinda** wanted to say*.

Comment: [...for reals...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22kinda+crazy.+Talks+to+himself.+Keeps%22) *He's **kinda** crazy. Talks to himself. Keeps patting his pocket. Maybe he's got some **kind of** good-luck charm in there or something*.

Comment: The object is the noun phrase "a kind of feeling this might happen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had a kind of feeling this might happen.

The **feeling** is the object.

Although "kind" can be a noun (which you could use with an article, for example "a kind") meaning "a particular sort of", that isn't how it is being idiomatically used here. "Kind of" is used as an *adverb*, and means 'to some extent'. The adverb is acting on the 'feeling'.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What about "had THE kind of feeling"<< kind is object? vs. "had A kind of feeling" << a kind of is "adverb" according to your explanation?

Comment: your explanation was:  a [blank] feeling(=a feeling) and " kind of" went into "blank"

Comment: "had the [blank] feeling(had the feeling)" and "kind of" as adverb went into that blank

Comment: The object is the noun phrase "a kind of feeling this might happen". "Kind of" is a dependent of "feeling" and the content clause "(that) this might happen" is complement of "feeling" and thus part of the noun phrase object.

Answer (score 0):

> I had a kind of feeling this might happen.

You can discover the answer by seeing what can be left out.

(a) I had a kind this might happen.

(b) I had a feeling this might happen.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for answer but I'd like to go "I had a kind of feeling(as a whole;not broken down; in terms of direct object of the verb "had")

Comment: I didn't understand that from your question. Yes, the noun phrase "kind of feeling" is the direct object. "Feeling" is not a gerund in this context. It is a noun.

Comment: gerund has both characteristics of noun and verb: that's why "of" is here and "that clasue" is here. "had a kind of feeling" << object is feeling? and "had the kind of feeling" << object is kind?

Comment: That is not my point. "Your **feeling** of sadness is not my concern" (noun) as opposed to "Your **feeling** sad is not my concern" (gerund).

Comment: The object in full is the noun phrase "a kind of feeling this might happen".